# Are these integers first converted to float and then added or they are added first and then converted to float in Java?

Tags: java, casting

`int a = 50;
int b = 60;
float c = float a + b;`
Now would these integers be added first and then converted to float or would they be converted to float first and then added?

Comment: This code doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: first added and than converted  float c = (float )(a + b);

Comment: The first one. Integer (after addition) then converted to float (assuming you had, correct, parenthesis there).

Answer (score 0):

If you have parenthesis as following, than two integers will be added first and the result will be converted into float.

```
float c = (float)(a + b);
```

And if you want to convert them into float first and than want to add than use following syntax:

```
float c = (float)a + (float)b;
```

If you are trying :

```
float c = (float)a + b;
```

Than only `a` will be converted to `float`, `b` will remain `int`.

But your syntax is wrong. You have to mention `float` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`float c = float a + b;` doesn't compile. I guess you mean (1)`float c = (float) a + b;` or (2)`float c = (float) (a + b);`

If you meant (1), `a` will be converted to a float first. Then `b` will be added to float value converted from `a`.

If you meant (2), `a + b` will be evaluated first and returns an `int` result. This `int` result is then converted to `float` and assigned to `c`.